# Authorization and Authentication mechanism in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have been using **GRAILS** since a year, It found very easy to implement security services  as it provides **spring source security plugin AND acegi.**

The features of that plugin are

**1) Create as many roles
2) Create users and assign them roles
3) Login and Logout**

So, I have not found any such thing in cakephp, **Is there any plugin, which provides Authentication and Authorization features as listed above**,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication is handled using the built-in Cake AuthComponent. It takes care of logging users in and out.

Authorization can be implemented in several different ways. For example, to authorize an entire controller to certain users, use the `'Controller'` authorization method and create a method in your controller like:

```
public function isAuthorized($user = null) {
    return $user['role'] == 'admin';
}
```

You can also do this in individual actions, or use a complete ACL setup.

Either way, read the manual: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html